# Combinatorics: possible combinations of integers with set product

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I'm currently struggling with combinatorics, specifically with the problem:

How many are the triplets of positive integers (x,y,z) such that x*y*z=84?

And others of the same type. Does it have to do with congruences?

Comment: It has more to do with prime factorisation.

Comment: A logical approach is to recognize that the factors have to be integers, so we are looking at some integers that multiply to $84$. Therefore, as @LordSharktheUnknown points out, this has very much to do with (prime) factorisation (of $84$, in specific).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any factor of $84 = 2^2 \cdot 3 \cdot 7$ has the form $2^{\alpha}3^{\beta}7^{\gamma}$.  If the three factors are $x = 2^{\alpha_1}3^{\beta_1}7^{\gamma_1}$, $y = 2^{\alpha_2}3^{\beta_2}7^{\gamma_2}$, and $z = 2^{\alpha_3}3^{\beta_3}7^{\gamma_3}$, then 
\begin{align*}
\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 + \alpha_3 & = 2 \tag{1}\\
\beta_1 + \beta_2 + \beta_3 & = 1 \tag{2}\\
\gamma_1 + \gamma_2 + \gamma_3 & = 1 \tag{3}
\end{align*}
Equations 1, 2, and 3 are equations in the nonnegative integers.  Clearly, equations 2 and 3 each have three solutions, depending on which of the three variables is equal to 1.  As for equation 1, a particular solution corresponds to the placement of two addition signs in a row of two ones.  For instance, 
$$1 + + 1$$
corresponds to the solution $\alpha_1 = 1$, $\alpha_2 = 0$, $\alpha_3 = 1$, while 
$$1 1 + +$$
corresponds to the solution $\alpha_1 = 2$, $\alpha_2 = \alpha_3 = 0$.  Thus, the number of solutions of equation 1 is the number of ways we can place two additions signs in a row of two ones, which is 
$$\binom{4}{2} = 6$$
since we must choose which two of the four positions required for two ones and two addition signs will be filled with addition signs.  Hence, the number of ordered triples $(x, y, z)$ such that $xyz = 84$ is $6 \cdot 3 \cdot 3 = 54$, as you found.

Answer (score 0):

How many ways can 84 = 2×2×3×7 be factored into three positive integers?

Comment: I think I'm getting it.
2^2 can be split among the factors either as two 2s or as a single 4:
4 0 0, 0 4 0, 0 0 4, 2 2 0, 2 0 2, 0 2 2
In 6 different combinations.
The other two prime factors 3 and 7 only have 3 positions each.
So the answer is 6x3x3= 54.
Is that correct?

Comment: @Moss That is correct.

Comment: @Moss.  As 0 is not a factor of 84,  4 0 0, etc needs some big explaning for that wrong answer.